# Is there a title that refers to the person who selects the athletes who will join the national team?

Tags: racing, terminology

Is there a title that refers to the person who selects the athletes who will integrate the national team (for instance, in the Olympic Games)? In football(soccer), there is a Selector ([Sélectionneur in French](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%A9lectionneur)) that will create the national team. What is the equivalent in bicycle racing?

Comment: Selector is the correct term in NZ and UK. Often selection is based on National Ranking but the selector(s) still has a say on team fit. They also have a role in talent identification and development.

Comment: @DWGKNZ thank you! Don't you want to turn your comment into an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: bribe receiver? (just kidding)

Answer (score 4):

The correct title in English speaking nations is Selector. The Selectors use their knowledge of the capabilities and nature of the riders to select those that represent their region or nation. Results are important but if look up any selection criteria you will quickly see behaviour standing out as one of if not the key decider on who gets to represent their country of the elite riders. Selectors work in groups and often are made up of head and team coaches and other national federation members.

Selectors also play a role in identifying talent and bring young riders into the high performance programs offered by the national federations.

There are many hoops to jump through before being selected as a representative. Firstly a rider must be eligible this involves:

- being a citizen
- holding a racing licence
- clean drug tests
- attend sanctioned events and training as required

Once eligible selection is then based on a number of factors:

- results and performances at national and international events
- UCI world cup points
- performance in selection trials
- ability to work well in a team
- would the athlete win an Olympic spot and could they go on to win a medal
- technique in team races
- behaviour and attitude
- sport science results
- fit in team composition (mainly in track events)

So in short, selection is based on not only results but a wider analysis of the rider. The Selectors still have a large role in ensuring that the national team is the best group of riders rather than the group of best riders.

Comment: Good, thorough answer. In your comment you also mentioned talent identification; do you think you can work that in somewhere?

Answer (score -3):

Unsure of what you're asking; from my limited knowledge of racing, teams, and the Olympics, I thought there were many privately sponsored teams, and if individuals want to become a part of the Olympic TeamUSA cycling team, they have to qualify based on their stats (e.g.: in [cat 1 races](http://www.usacycling.org/road-category-upgrade-guidelines.htm)) It doesn't seem like there would be a stand-alone position for a person to select them, other than perhaps the Olympic team coach.

Anyone who knows more about this, please correct me where needed!

Comment: Maybe this is country-dependent; I am from Portugal and as far as I know here there is only one person who selects the athletes for the big international competitions...